# time is late in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Joomla 2.5 displays wrong datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637322/joomla-2-5-displays-wrong-datetime)

i am trying to display current date and time in my component as below:

```
<?php                   
$date =& JFactory::getDate();
echo 'Current date and time is: ' . $date->toFormat() . "\n";
?>
```

i've set the timezone to **Asia/Dhaka** in my machine, joomla server configuration and even in php.ini but still the returned value is 6 hours late. Please suggest me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using JFactory::getDate('now') to use the server's current time. If that doesn't help you can add the second option to set your timezone offset.

Since I'm East coast US, I would use to force EST:

```
JFactory::getDate('now' , -5)
```

Comment: no that doesn't help. i tried both the option. i even cleared the browser cache hoping that would be the culprit.

Comment: as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637322/joomla-2-5-displays-wrong-datetime?rq=1, using of JHtml::date() did the trick